# joomla component allocator showing 505 internal server error

Tags: jquery, joomla, components

When I try to go through the form on http://www.mrmarketology.com/component/com_allocator/ it stalls when you select a package and date. It does not go to the next step.

When i press ok it show me 505 internal server error in console. Please help.

**Site link** : http://www.mrmarketology.com/component/com_allocator/

**Demo link of component** : http://demo2.profinvent.com/index.php/sport-halls-to-rent?view=booking&venue_id=1

Comment: Set error reporting to maximum in your joomla configuration. then you should see a proper error message.

Comment: It is showing error due to cloud flare minify javascript

Comment: What is the error message? Is that added by a plugin? Disable the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected now not using minify JavaScript.

It is showing error due to cloud flare minify JavaScript